# Curve genereated by a hanging rope with both ends hold together

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

So a hanging rope assumes the form of a catenary, but if the ends are together it takes some kind of "drop" shape. I think that if the rope is perfectly flexible the shape is a vertical line but what happens if it has some stiffness?

Comment: [This](http://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/chainette/chainetteelastique.shtml) is in French, but you might be interested in it anyway...

Comment: I guess you should decide how to model stiffness in order to get an answer...